# Ionic Android App crashes with OKHTTP Error

Tags: ionic-framework, okhttp, androidx

I had this error message when I upgraded to cordova android 9.0.0 as my android app crashed:

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getHttpUrlChecked(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl; in class Lokhttp3/internal/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Internal' appears in /data/app/~~3-MBW_s69OAEvUshu6r5KQ==/com.myapp-uqt8D3INmPivQDNZ8Nrevg==/base.apk)
    at okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpURLConnection.buildCall(OkHttpURLConnection.java:373)
    at okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(OkHttpURLConnection.java:260)
    at okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:229)
    at okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(OkHttpsURLConnection.java:26)
    at com.silkimen.http.HttpRequest.openOutput(HttpRequest.java:2599)
    at com.silkimen.http.HttpRequest.form(HttpRequest.java:3005)
    at com.silkimen.http.HttpRequest.form(HttpRequest.java:2967)
    at com.silkimen.http.HttpRequest.form(HttpRequest.java:3029)
    at com.silkimen.http.HttpRequest.form(HttpRequest.java:2938)
    at com.silkimen.cordovahttp.CordovaHttpBase.sendBody(CordovaHttpBase.java:167)
    at com.silkimen.cordovahttp.CordovaHttpBase.run(CordovaHttpBase.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I did a grep search for every single file in my project and changed every dependency to the same version of OKHTTP: 3.10.1
But the error still occurs.

My Ionic Info:

```
    Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1002.0
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.12
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.15
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 30 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.11.0
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v12.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```

I know that launchnavigator and advanced http need to have the same okhttp version and they both have 3.10.1.
My Plugins:

```
call-number 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
com-badrit-base64 0.2.0 "Base64"
cordova-instagram-plugin 0.5.8 "Instagram"
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.5.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-androidx 3.0.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-brightness 0.1.5 "Brightness"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-contacts 3.0.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-crop 0.3.1 "CropPlugin"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.9.2 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.5.8 "cordova-plugin-filepath"
cordova-plugin-image-picker 1.1.1 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-market 1.2.0 "Market"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-photo-library 2.2.1 "Photo Library"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.4 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-universal-clipboard 0.1.0 "Clipboard"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 5.0.5 "Launch Navigator"
```

thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are likely mixing OkHttp module versions.  You should try bumping *up* to all modules 3.12.13 or 4.9.1

With a gradle build you would use the BOM which strictly matches the version across a project, see https://github.com/square/okhttp#releases

```
    dependencies {
       // define a BOM and its version
       implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.1"))

       // define any required OkHttp artifacts without version
       implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
       implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")
    }
```